# Java list best practice

Tags: java, iteration, containers

I need some container to keep elements so, if I'll try to get the size()+i element, i'll get  element number i. Or with iterator, which starts from the beginning of container after it tries to get the last element? What are the best practicies in both cases? I mean performance and easy useability.

Comment: I think that's called a "ring buffer", or a "circular buffer". Not sure about Java, C++ has one in Boost...

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to have such a data structure?  What do you need it for?

Comment: I have a DodgerAI class, which handles AI for some hero in game. It has a field - index of hero and field, representing game logic. There are many situations in AI (method in DodgerAI), when all heros, except hero, controlled by AI, must be analyzed. Thats why I want to use some kind of "ring".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, just ask for `n % list.size()` perhaps?

For the iterator part, create a class that wraps an iterator, and when next() returns null, just have it reset the iterator.

Answer (score 9):

You could create a simple subclass of `ArrayList<T>` and override the `get(int n)` method as follows:

```
public T get(int n)
{
    return super.get(n % this.size());
}
```

As to the iterator, you will need to implement your own, which shouldn't be all that hard.

EDIT:

Assuming your new class is called RingList, here's a sample RingIterator (untested):

```
public class RingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
{
    private int cur = 0;
    private RingList<T> coll = null;

    protected RingIterator(RingList<T> coll) { this.coll = coll; }
    public boolean hasNext() { return size() > 0; }
    public T next() 
    { 
        if (!hasNext()) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        int i=cur++; 
        cur=cur%size(); 
        return coll.get(i);
    }
    public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
}
```

You would then override the `iterator()` method in `RingList<T>` as

```
public Iterator<T> iterator()
{
    return new RingIterator(this);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't all methods (`remove` etc) use the same indexing not just `get`? Mini-bug: When `cur` wraps..

Comment: @dacwe: Of course.  I could say "left as an exercise for the reader" :-)

Comment: :-) Great, now it's just the case with an empty list, but that we leave ;-)

Comment: It seems the empty list state has been implemented as well in the code above, so it wasn't left :).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, thats what I've created:

```
public class RingIterator<E> {
private List<E> _lst;
private ListIterator<E> _lstIter;

public RingIterator(ListIterator<E> iter, List<E> lst) {
    super();
    _lstIter = iter;
    _lst = lst;
}

public E next() {
    if(!_lstIter.hasNext())
        _lstIter = _lst.listIterator();
    return _lstIter.next();
}

public E previous() {
    if(!_lstIter.hasPrevious())
        _lstIter = _lst.listIterator(_lst.size());
    return _lstIter.previous();
}
```

}

Then get method:

```
/*
 * Returns ring iterator,
 * use it with 'ParentClass' type.
 */
public RingIterator<SubClass> getRingIter(int i) {
    return new RingIterator(_subs.listIterator(i),_subs);
}
```

And I use it:

```
RingIterator<SubClass> ri = _logic.getRingIter(1);
ParentClass ai = ri.next();
```

I wanted to make only type ParentClass (not SubClass) available via getRingIter, but I don't see a way to do it with no creation of List - convertion of List.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the ArrayList class and implement the `get(Integer)` method the way you like. I think this is the 'best practice'.